# Why my javascript code doesnt show "Not Found"?

Tags: javascript, function, return

it doesnt show `Not Found`, it shows `undefined`

```js
function checkObj(obj, checkprob) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty) {
    return obj[checkprob];
  } else {
    return "Not Found"
  }
}

console.log(checkObj({
  gift: "pony",
  pet: "kitten",
  bed: "sleigh"
}, "Amir"))
```

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` expects property name as a parameter, isn't it?

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and you will see how to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty` is a method and it takes a parameter. You have to call it like this `hasOwnProperty(checkprob)`. See also the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

```js
function checkObj(obj, checkprob) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(checkprob)) {
    return obj[checkprob];
  } else {
    return "Not Found"
  }
}

console.log(checkObj({
  gift: "pony",
  pet: "kitten",
  bed: "sleigh"
}, "Amir"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `hasOwnProperty` wrong:

```js
function checkObj(obj, checkprob){
     if(obj.hasOwnProperty(checkprob)){
          return obj[checkprob];
     } else{
          return "Not Found";
     } 
}
console.log(checkObj({gift: "pony", pet: "kitten", bed: "sleigh"}, "Amir"));
console.log(checkObj({gift: "pony", pet: "kitten", bed: "sleigh"}, "bed"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing function call. You can also use `in` operator.

```
function checkObj(obj, checkprob){
     if(obj.hasOwnProperty(checkprob)){
          return obj[checkprob];
     } else{
          return "Not Found";
     } 
}


    function checkObj2(obj, checkprob) {
      if (checkprob in obj) {
        return obj[checkprob];
      } else {
        return "Not Found";
      }
    }

    console.log(
      checkObj2(
        {
          gift: "pony",
          pet: "kitten",
          bed: "sleigh"
        },
        "Amir"
      )
    );
```